# django many to many with 3 models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I am creating a ticket app, the app has 3 models: Ticket, Parent, Variation. The variation model has a one to many relationship with Parent, and ticket has a m2m with Variation.
What i am trying to do is be able to select a parent and/or variation from the add ticket page, but using the filter_vertical or something similar, that way i can choose one or the other from the same drop down . heres the models.py

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        (0, "Open"),
        (1, "Closed"),
    )

    status = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0,choices=STATUS)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    product = models.ManyToManyField(Variation)
    parent = models.ManyToManyField(Parent)
    submitted_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

class Variation(models.Model):

    qb = models.IntegerField(unique=True, verbose_name="QuickBooks #")
    parent = models.ForeignKey("Parent")

class Parent(models.Model):
    item = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="product #")
    date = models.DateField()
```

any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: i think you do'nt actually need the `Ticket.parent` as you have `Ticket.product.parent_set` (or something like that. So defining it on the Variations AND Ticket is redundant(?) Is there some reason you need it?

Comment: i was testing to see if i could choose both from same drop down, so as a temporary solution i added the m2m to parent

Comment: I really think the idea of having it on both is not a good one. If you want access from `Ticket` create a property and in the set function do the work to set them both.

Comment: true, but how can i get the admin to show both models in same dropdown ?

Comment: Admin? Ah you didn't specify that so I assumed you meant user side. The django admin is a pain (imho) to alter its behaviour and i'd start writing my own admin views if you want spmething specific like that. But Someone else might have a better idea then that. Also you should put this information in your post and add the tag `django-admin`